# Flurl's PostUrlEncodedAsync is ignoring JsonProperty names

Tags: c#, json.net, flurl

I'm using Flurl (one of my favorite APIs) to now post form-data to a url.  I'm quite familiar using 'JsonProperty' attributes to name the keys, and use standard casing for c#.

But when I use PostUrlEncodedAsync, the normal JsonProperty code doesn't convert to 'key', but remains 'KeyName' and the call fails.

```
public class TokenTest
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm a little baffled that this doesn't work right out of the box.

```
var request = new TokenTest
{
   KeyName = "ewr1-QuQ5jo88WfCpNPz2kTb8ES",
};

var result = await url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(request).ReceiveString();
```

My call fails since it wants 'key', but I'm sending 'KeyName'.  JsonProperty/DataMember attributes have always worked in the past, so why is it failing here?

---

As I work on the problem, it seems to stem from the fact that this method calls `DefaultUrlEncodedSerializer` to do the serialization.  This serializer ignores the JsonProperty names.

```
   var urlEncodedContent = new CapturedUrlEncodedContent(request.Settings.UrlEncodedSerializer.Serialize(token));
   var jsonEncodedContent = new CapturedUrlEncodedContent(request.Settings.JsonSerializer.Serialize(token));
```

For example, the jsonEncodedContent uses the `JsonProperty` attribute, while the urlEncodedContent ignores the attribute.

Comment: pretty sure you need to add a custom serializer

Comment: I'm seeing that, but do you not think it's a little strange that the UrlEncoderSerializer ignores the JsonProperty attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JsonProperty`, as the name implies, is related to JSON serialization. It's actually a Json.NET feature; the fact that it works with Flurl is just a convenient consequence of the fact that Flurl uses Json.NET in its default JSON serializer. But I don't think it's reasonable to expect something called `JsonProperty` to work with URL-encoding, because URL-encoding has nothing to do with JSON.

You can work around this pretty easily by just projecting onto an anonymous object:

```
url.PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { key = token.KeyName });
```

Not as clean or type-safe, but I've always found this to be acceptable since URL-encoded data tends to be smaller/flatter/simpler than JSON payloads, on average.

Comment: You do have an excellent point, and I'll have to say you did give the right answer to my question.  But I literally changed my actual attribute name `[DataMember(Name="key")]` to `JsonProperty` to make the question easier and attract a bigger audience. 

I've added a message on the Flurl github and see if this is their intended functionality.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: :) And I just now realized who you were Todd, thanks a ton for an absolutely fantastic product.

Comment: Yeah, "they" is mostly me. :) Thanks for the kind words. Feel free to open a suggestion related to this, it's been brought up at least once before and I might consider something for a future release.